# ComboBox ItemTemplate does not support values of type 'Image'

Tags: wpf, image, binding, combobox, itemtemplate

I'm trying to bind a WPF combobox to an observable collection of images.
Here is my collection:

```
    public class AvatarPhoto
    {
        public int AvatarId { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage AvatarImage { get; set; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<AvatarPhoto> AvailableProfilePictures { get; private set; }
```

Here is my xaml:
[image]

Visual Studio gives me this compile time error:
Property 'ItemTemplate' does not support values of type 'Image'.

Why is this error seen?

Thanks

Update: thanks for the answer! It solved the problem.

Now I have updated my code but I'm seeing this in the ComboBox:
[image]

Why is it not displaying pictures correctly? In the debug window I can see my collection is correctly populated:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your `Image` in a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```